# Find specific parent of element in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a list setup like so

```
<div id="timelineRight" data-sticky-to="#rightpanel">
    <ul class="timelineHighlights">
        <li>
            <a href="">2015</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" spy="2015-07">July</a></li>
                <li><a href="" spy="2015-06">June</a></li>
                <li><a href="" spy="2015-05">May</a></li>
                ...
```

I have a function that gets called when page scrolling should change the navigation in this list.  This works but what I want to do is also add a class to the parent on scrolling.

I.e. if `June` is highlighted (using `current` class) then I also want `2015` to be highlighted.

Currently my code to add the class looks like so:

```
elem.addClass("current");
```

In straight up jQuery, the selector I'd like to us is the following:

```
elem.closest("ul").closest("li").find("a").first().addClass("current")
```

Comment: `elem.closest('.timelineHighlights li>a').addClass('current')`

Comment: @Tushar not if jq-lite is used

Comment: Try this elem.parent("ul").parent("li").find("a").first().addClass("current")

Comment: @ShubhamNigam `elem.parent()` works but `elem.parent("selector")` doesnt

Comment: Why don't you add a directive to the other element as well?